# GA: How to access Cohort Analysis via Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

**Cohort** dimensions and metrics are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts). Yet, when I try to query it using API (e.g. using [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)) an error 400 occurs.

One of queries I've tried is: `metrics = ga:cohortActiveUsers` and `dimensions = ga:cohortNthDay` .

Is is possible to query **Cohort Analysis** report via API?

Comment: I am going to email the developers and log an issue I think you found a bug.

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. Query explorer complains that "selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together", yet the docs say "This metric is relevant in the context of ga:cohortNthDay/ ga:cohortNthWeek/ ga:cohortNthMonth."

Comment: Logged https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=928 Sending an email off now.

Comment: Just add ga:cohortAppviewsPerUserWithLifetimeCriteria as a single metric no dimensions.  Its not valid with itself.

Comment: Error occurred again

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because the [Query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) uses the v3 of the Google Analytics API. If you look at the [Dimensions and Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts) you will notice that these dimensions were added in the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).

The error message you are getting is incorrect and should be corrected soon.  It should state something more like `This metric cannot be used in Version 3 of the API`.  You caught this while we where in the process of rolling out the new API. Which has now been officially released see change [log](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/changelog)

To make use of these new dimensions and metrics you must construct a [V4 cohort request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts):

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests": [{
    "viewId": "XXXX",
    # No date range is required in the request
    "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:cohort" },{"name": "ga:cohortNthDay" }],
    "metrics": [
      {"expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers" },
      {"expression": "ga:cohortTotalUsers"}
    ],
    "cohortGroup": {
      "cohorts": [{
        "name": "cohort 1",
        "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
        "dateRange": { "startDate": "2015-08-01", "endDate": "2015-08-01"}
      },{
        "name": "cohort 2",
        "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
        "dateRange": {"startDate": "2015-07-01", "endDate": "2015-07-01"}
      }]
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compose a cohort requests by using the [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/) tool, in the **Cohort Request** tab.

As you select the options in the **Set query parameters** section, the request payload is shown below.

Hope it helps.